# How to Deserialize Anchor Accounts from Other Programs in Accounts Struct

Tags: anchor-lang

I have something like the following in my account struct for one of my instructions

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct DripOrcaWhirlpool<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    /// CHECK: Temporary
    pub whirlpool: Box<Account<'info, Whirlpool>>,

}
```

I copied the `Whirlpool` from the orca whirlpool repo, and I am passing in whirlpool accounts owned by the orca whirlpool program into my instruction. However, I get the following error with this setup.

```
  logs: [
    'Program dripTrkvSyQKvkyWg7oi4jmeEGMA5scSYowHArJ9Vwk invoke [1]',
    'Program log: Instruction: DripOrcaWhirlpool',
    'Program log: AnchorError caused by account: whirlpool. Error Code: AccountOwnedByWrongProgram. Error Number: 3007. Error Message: The given account is owned by a different program than expected.',
    'Program log: Left:',
    'Program log: whirLbMiicVdio4qvUfM5KAg6Ct8VwpYzGff3uctyCc',
    'Program log: Right:',
    'Program log: dripTrkvSyQKvkyWg7oi4jmeEGMA5scSYowHArJ9Vwk',
  ]
```

Comment: Does it deserialise fine without `#[account(mut)]`?

Answer (score 1):

My fix was to create a dummy program in my project with the correct `declare_id!` set.